# SQL Server: how do I find the most common string in a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with 1,000,000+ records and I would like to find the most common sub string that is at least 5 characters long.

If I have the following entries:

```
KDHFOUDHGOENWFIJ 1114H4363SDFHDHGFDG
GSDLGJSLJSKJDFSG 1114H20SDGDSSFHGSLD
SLSJDHLJKSSDJFKD 1114HJSDHFJKSDKFSGG
```

I would like to write in SQL a statement that selects `1114H` as the most commmon sub string. How can I do this?

**Notes:**

- The substring does not have to be in the same location.
- The subtrings must be length 5
- The maximum length of each record is 50 characters

Comment: Does the substring have to be in the same location within the string in all rows?

Comment: You will ultimately need to find all substrings of the required minimum length /and/ the frequency of occurrence of each substring. Is this degree of logic appropriate at the data level? Should you not consider this at the application level?

Comment: If it has to be at least 5 char long it means it has to be exactly 5 chars long if the dataset has any entropy at all. Doing it in the SQL is not smart thing to try especially on larger sets. There are some really fast algorithms that will do it much, much faster on the dataset out of the database.  IDeally, you can adapt a part of LZW compression algorithm to do exactly what you want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel–Ziv–Welch

Comment: Actually the 'most common substring' in your example would be ` 1114H`, which is 6 characters long. Any reason why you didn't consider space a valid part of the substring?

Comment: If I were doing it in SQL, I'd write all of the valid substrings from each base row out to a separate table, and then simply group by the substring and count its instances. If I had to handle changing data, a trigger would call an SP to keep the substrings table current with the base table. P.S. I would not allow this application on my server if it attempted to do this task without the sort of preprocessing I describe above. I imagine it would be a CPU hog and would not be something we'd put into production for general use.

Comment: You could probably accomplish this with a recursive CTE, but see caveat above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no requirement to find the longest substring so every substring with length greater than 5 will always have a substring of 5 characters that is a tie for count. So we only have to check substrings of length 5.

In the sample data there are three strings that occur three times.  `_1114H`,  `_1114` and  `1114H` (`_` is to show the location of a space ).

In this solution `master..spt_values` is used in place of a numbers table.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity,
  Data varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values
('KDHFOUDHGOENWFIJ 1114H4363SDFHDHGFDG'),
('GSDLGJSLJSKJDFSG 1114H20SDGDSSFHGSLD'),
('SLSJDHLJKSSDJFKD 1114HJSDHFJKSDKFSGG')

select top 1 substring(T.Data, N.Number, 5) as Word
from @T as T
  cross apply (select N.Number
               from master..spt_values as N
               where N.type = 'P' and
                     N.number between 1 and len(T.Data)-4) as N
group by substring(T.Data, N.Number, 5)                      
order by count(distinct id) desc
```

Result:

```
Word
------
 1114
```

Comment: Edited post to remove redundancy re: 5-50

Comment: @hamlin11 - Ok. Then I remove the edit. Was not too happy about that one anyway. Building a string result set with length 5 is probably not very fast. And finding the longest string using an extra cross apply will probably be some 50 times slower still.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question in full, but here is an article from a book about advanced search techniques where it mentions a user-defined function "LCS" (longest common substring) that might be helpful:

http://books.google.com/books?id=wGwVkAt79bEC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=sql+full+text+common+substring&source=bl&ots=fveHa8an08&sig=VTWHQDTA6gqSNylY9oR0mPhcP6Y&hl=en&ei=iALcTd_AB-j00gG3iZ3lDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: From the question he wants to find the most common, not the longest common string. Or I am missing something?